# In kubernetes, what's the difference between the command forms in YAML specs?

Tags: kubernetes

In the YAML specs you can do either of these. Is it the same confusion as docker's cmd vs exec forms for ENTRYPOINT?

```
command: ["cmd1", "cmd2"]
args: ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

vs

```
command:
  - cmd1
  - cmd1
args:
  - arg1
  - arg2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two notations are exactly the same; in YAML, they're both valid representations of a list (remember that YAML is a superset of JSON, so every valid JSON construct is also valid in YAML).

The first notation (`["cmd1", "cmd"]`) is called a [*flow sequence* in the official specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790320), while the second notation (`- cmd1 ...`) is a [*block sequence*](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797382). They are both parsed into the exact same data structure. Using one over the other is just a matter of taste.